# High current thermal bypass

Tags: current, shunt, bypass

I am using a shunt to measure the current on a 12V system on a boat. Most currents are very low (under 4 A) but when using the starter the peak current reach peaks of 250 A.

I've sized the shunt to 50 A to ensure sufficient precision on the measurements (there is a 1% error, if a 300 A shunt would be used, that would show potentially 3 additional A). However there is the risk of overheating when using the starter.

I was thinking of installing some sort of thermal protection, where the shunt would be bypassed if it reaches a certain temperature. I've tried looking for some sort thermal automatic resetting fuse or switch but do not find anything that could accept so much current.

Do you have any suggestion?

Thank you very much

Comment: Why use a shunt and not a hall effect device? Or use two shunts or two hall effect devices or one of each to measure the start current and the non-start current. That way you can get the resolution where you need it.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, my understanding is that a hall effect ring would be less accurate than a shunt, and with two shunts I would have two separate counters, each showing only part of the consumption (and recharging).

Answer (score 1):

Move the starter motor connection to the battery and before the shunt.

Use the starter motor cable as a separate shunt if you need to measure starter current. You could calculate is resistance by measuring the length and diameter, by measuring its resistance (difficult) or calibration with a clamp-on DC meter. Resistance will increase as it heats up but it might be good enough for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have also thought of putting a second higher rater shunt, but then I would have two meters and neither would show the full picture.



As it is important that the starter always works, in ideal conditions (warm temperatures, recently used) it only takes about 70A during 3 seconds, but in the worst conditions  it might take 10+seconds at 250A, I was thinking that having a possibility to automatically bypass the shunt if the temperature goes too high would be ideal.

Comment: OK, but what is the purpose of the exercise?

Comment: It is to measure the state of charge of the batteries and the live consumption (meaning I can then easily see when I need to recharge the batteries and manage the consumption).  The bypass would only be used occasionally and the meter would not take that into account but I'm fine with that.